# Saving int value into Eeprom and loading it back into a value again

Tags: c, arduino, esp32

so i am trying to save an integer value into Eeprom and load it back into a value again. But the problem is, that i can't load the saved int value correctly into the new int value.

I am doing this, because I want to compare the new int value with the already saved one, to control a stepper motor with the rotations got from that value.

```
void SaveParam(int* param) {
    Serial.print("Saving Param: ");
    //Serial.println(param);
    EEPROM.begin(512);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        EEPROM.write(i+500, (int)param[i]);
    EEPROM.end();
}

int LoadParam(){
    int b[10];
    EEPROM.begin(512);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        b[i]= byte(EEPROM.read(i+500));   
    EEPROM.end();
    return b[10];
}


// main part
int b = (int)LoadParam();
int* val = &i;

if (i>b) {
    Serial.print("Motor is going down (clockwise) ");    
    MotorMoveDown(i);
    SaveParam(val);
    Serial.println(b);
} else if (i<b) {
    Serial.print("Motor is going up (counter-clockwise)"); 
    MotorMove(i);
}
```

Comment: You are calling SaveParam() with a pointer to val as argument, and val is a pointer to i but you are trying to print the b value, could you clarify that ?

Comment: Yeah so actually the thing is that I want to compare two integer values. Idea: I receive a request from a wlan bridge and I am saving the integer value  I received from the Bridge into the EEPROM with the method SaveParam(int* param). Next, I want to load this integer value back into a variable with the method LoadParam() to compare the new int value from the bridge request with the old one from the bridge, which was saved, to know if I should rotate the stepper motor up or down.

Comment: My point was, is the problem about the save/load function from eeprom or is it about your code on top of it ? I understand your point of view but please, give us a code that is small and with the problem like: "int b = 5; saveparam(b); int c = loadParam(); if (b != c) print("error")"

Comment: SaveParam() writes 4 integers to EEPROM, starting with the one at the address passed in param (this might be what you want).  LoadParam() reads 4 integers from EEPROM into an array with space for ten integers, then returns the eleventh element from the array.  You need to fix both of these functions before you can even think about using the value returned by LoadParam().